# What does Pac Booster do in Ms. Pacman (Tengen)?

Tags: ms-pacman-tengen

In Tengen's port of *Ms. Pacman* for the NES, the options menu has a setting called "Pac Booster".

What does the Pac Booster option do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pac Booster increases the player's movement speed to around double speed.**

There are 3 different settings for Pac Booster:

- Off
- Use A or B
- Always on

The second option will activate Pac Booster when holding down A or B. There does not appear to be any disadvantage or score penalty for leaving Pac Booster enabled.

For comparison, see gameplay with [Pac Booster off](https://youtu.be/0XSL1SN3MuY?t=10) versus gameplay with [Pac Booster on](https://youtu.be/t_bUrJmCUyA?t=41).